# Automapper child entities not mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

Im trying to map a parent entity that includes a default child entity.

So, I have a `promotion` object, that has a collection of `localisedPromotion` objects

I want to set a specific `localisedPromotion` and set it as my `defaultLocalisedPromotion`

In my config I have:

```
config.CreateMap<LocalisedPromotion, LocalisedPromotionViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LocalisedPromotionId, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Id));

config.CreateMap<Promotion, PromotionViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DefaultLocalisedPromotion,
               o => o.MapFrom(src => src.LocalisedPromotions
                                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CultureId == src.DefaultCultureId)));
```

So in my mind this should set the field `DefaultLocalisedPromotion` of type `LocalisedPromotionViewModel`

However the field is always null

Is there an obvious way of doing what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a unit test and it seems that the AutoMapper code works. Please review the unit test and let me know if it is correct or post more code (especially the classes you want to map) so that the test can be adapted.

```
using AutoMapper;
using Xunit;

using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AutoMapperTest
{
    public class LocalisedPromotion
    {
        public int Id;
        public int CultureId;
    }

    public class LocalisedPromotionViewModel
    {
        public int LocalisedPromotionId;
    }

    public class Promotion
    {
        public List<LocalisedPromotion> LocalisedPromotions;
        public int DefaultCultureId;
    }

    public class PromotionViewModel
    {
        public LocalisedPromotionViewModel DefaultLocalisedPromotion;
    }

    public class AutoMapperTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            var theConfig = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
            {
                config.CreateMap<LocalisedPromotion, LocalisedPromotionViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.LocalisedPromotionId, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Id));

                config.CreateMap<Promotion, PromotionViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.DefaultLocalisedPromotion,
                               o => o.MapFrom(src => src.LocalisedPromotions
                                                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.CultureId == src.DefaultCultureId)));
            });

            var promotion = new Promotion { DefaultCultureId = 3 };
            promotion.LocalisedPromotions = new List<LocalisedPromotion>() { new LocalisedPromotion() { Id = 1, CultureId = 3 } };

            var result = theConfig.CreateMapper().Map<Promotion, PromotionViewModel>(promotion);

            Assert.NotNull(result.DefaultLocalisedPromotion);
            Assert.Equal(result.DefaultLocalisedPromotion.LocalisedPromotionId, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats strange, your test works for me too, even when I swap out your classes for the actual classes used in the application. Will need to investigate further I guess

Comment: Did you already find out what caused the problem in your code?

Comment: Yes I did. The fact that it worked in the test but not in the App pointed to there being something wrong in the config file. I had config.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true; in that file. Mapping worked as normal when I commented this out. Thanks for taking a look.